# How to increase the effect of \bigl / \bigr with unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, brackets, delimiters

I am writing in fontsize 12pt and use lualatex (`LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)`). Additionally I use the `unicode-math` package.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\[a\Biggl(b\biggl(c\Bigl(d\bigl(e(x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)\]
\end{document}
```

This leads to the following result:
[image: The output of the MWE.]

The pair of parentheses that are "influenced" by `\bigl` / `\bigr`, those around `e(x)`, are larger than the parentheses where no special command has been applied to, those around `x`; exactly as it was my intention when writing.

But the difference in size is very small and the growth from `\bigl` to `\Bigl` seems much larger than the growth from `\Bigl` to `\biggl` or from `\biggl` to `\Biggl`.

How can I modify the `\bigl` / `\bigr` commands such that the resulting parentheses have a size more or less "average" between `()` and `\Bigl(\Bigr)`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unicode math fonts often have more than the 1+4 sizes of delimiters. The ones for Latin Modern can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GlPS.png). As is now answered by David, one can control the sizes. (I guess that the numbers he gives are thresholds and that it is somehow mapped to the available sizes.)

Comment: @mickep Where can I learn more about the sizes of delimiters available in Latin Modern?

Comment: One way would be to look into the font in for example fontforge. I generated the picture with ConTeXt, which has a mechanism for showing all available variants (good for debugging).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition in `unicode-math` comes from `amsmath` which is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
```

so the sizes are 1, 1.5, 2 and 2.5 times the size of a strutbox, you could redefine to whatever multiples you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\big}{\bBigg@{1.2}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.7}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@{2.2}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[a\Biggl(b\biggl(c\Bigl(d\bigl(e(x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Based on your answer I could find values that I am happy with.